# Route request from 1VM to another

Tags: linux, networking, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a linux ubuntu vm and windows xp vm running parallel.

How would I go about routing a request from the xp vm to the linux vm?

Host PC is setup to route test.com to 192.168.33.10 which is the ip of the VM
I've tried modifying the host on the windows xp machine to route to host machine then through to linux but cant get it working.

What ip would I need to target in windows xp host file?

Answer (score 0):

Your VMs probably aren't connected with each other. To verify that, try pinging one from another. If they won't recognize each other's IPs, then you have to setup a NAT network for them.

1. Open VirtualBox Preferences.

   [image: VirtualBox menu with Preferences highlighted]
2. Navigate to *Network* and click the *Add NAT network* button.

   [image: Preferences window with Network section visible and Add NAT network button highlighted]
3. A new network will appear. Click *OK*.
4. Open first VM's settings.

   [image: VM context menu with Settings highlighted]
5. Navigate to *Network* section and change *Attached to:* to *NAT network*.

   [image: VM network settings with NAT network selected]
6. Click *OK*. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for other VMs you want to connect into one network.

Some settings may not be available when VMs are running. You may also have to reboot them or even restart VirtualBox to apply new settings.